# From basic plot to ggplot, how to convert cex for symbol size

Tags: r, ggplot2

A friend of mine helped me creating a code to generate a scatter plot using the basic plot function. Now I would like to make the same plot using ggplot, however I do not know/understand how to convert cex parameter of the basic plot function in the corresponding ggplot option.

This is an example of my data

```
df=read.table(text="
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
    1   2   3   4   5   1   2   3   4   5
    2   3   4   5   6   2   3   4   5   6
    3   4   5   6   7   3   4   5   6   7
    4   5   6   7   8   4   5   6   7   8
    5   6   7   8   9   5   6   7   8   9
    6   7   8   9   10  6   7   8   9   10
    7   8   9   10  11  7   8   9   10  11
    8   9   10  11  12  8   9   10  11  12
    9   10  11  12  13  9   10  11  12  13",header=T)
```

And the is the code I use for the basic plot function

```
temp <- as.matrix(df)
x <- ncol(temp)/2
y <- nrow(temp)
maxtemp  <- max(temp [ , 1:x], na.rm = T)
plot(rep(1, y) ~ temp [, x + 1], type = "p", pch = 1, cex = 5*temp [, 1]/maxtemp , xlim = c(0, 15), ylim = c(0,6))
for(i in 1:(x-1)){
  points(rep(1 + i, y) ~ temp [, x + 1 + i], type = "p", pch = 1, cex = 5*temp [, 1 + i]/maxtemp)
  next}
```

To make the same plot in ggplot I wrote this code, however I do not get the same picture, the size of the dots is not the same, and I guess this is due to the fact that plot uses cex, while ggplot uses size, and I do not know how to deal with this...

```
    temp <- data.table(df)
    colnames(temp) <- c(paste("I",c(1:5), sep=""), c(1:5))
x <- ncol(temp)/2    
maxtemp  <- max(temp [ , 1:x], na.rm = T)

    for(t in 1:5){
      temp[, t] <- 5*temp[, t, with = FALSE]/maxtemp
      next}
    #I do this to create the 'cex' values, as cex does not exist in ggplot

    ggplot(gather(temp[, 6:10]),aes(x = value, y = as.numeric(key))) + geom_point(aes(size = gather(temp[, 1:5])$value), shape = 1) + xlim(0, 15) + ylim(0, 6) + theme_bw() +  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + xlab("") + ylab("")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't define "n" in the second block of code.

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake, it should have been "x" insted of "n".

Comment: `?scale_size_identity` uses size values without scaling.

Comment: But I want to scale, as cex does for the basic plot

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think I found a way to do what I wanted.
I was looking for something else and I came across the following sentence in the reference manual of ggplot2

```
# To set aesthetics, wrap in I()
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = I("red"))
```

So I gave it a try and after few attempts I ended up with the following code

```
ggplot(gather(temp[, 6:10]),aes(x = value, y = as.numeric(key))) + geom_point(aes(size = I(gather(temp[, 1:5])$value*2)), shape = 1) + xlim(0, 15) + ylim(0, 6) + theme_bw() +  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + xlab("") + ylab("")
```

Using `aes(size = I(gather(temp[, 1:5])$value*2))` I get almost exactly the same plot as if I use the plot() function (first block of code).
I do not fully understand the relationship between `cex` and `aes(I())`, but it does what I was looking for. Maybe someone can comment on this.

Comment: My comment is: don't do this! I() is meant only for qplot to distinguish set vs mapped values. aes() should never contain $ or [, ].